# How can we initiate another jQuery plugin inside jQuery Datatable call results instead of page ready function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

For my web application, iam using jQuery datatable with ajax to fetch data from database.Actually 'icheck' is initiated in jQuery page ready function.What the problem is after calling datatable or any filter or search happens in datatable, getting data correctly and icheck check boxes are showing as normal check boxes.
How can i recall the icheck plugin call inside datatable call.My Code is as follows

```
<table id="viewcat" class="table table-bordered table-striped mar-bottom0 mydatatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 9%"><input type="checkbox" class="minimal" id="bulkDelete" /> <button type="submit" id="deleteTriger" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs hor-align" value="Delete Selected" >Delete</button></th>
      <th style="width: 2%">Sl.no</th>
      <th style="width: 15%">Category Name</th>                  
      <th style="width: 20%">Reference Links</th>
      <th style="width: 25%">Image</th>
      <th style="width: 15%"></th>
      <th style="width: 10%"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>                  
</table>
```

Script is as follows

```
<script>
  $(function (){    
    $("#viewcat").DataTable({
      "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){               
               $("td:nth-child(2)", nRow).append(aData[7]);
               return nRow;
            },      
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "order": [ 2, "asc" ],
      "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 4, 5 ,6] } ],
      "ajax":{
          url :"maincategory/viewdata.php", // json datasource
          type: "post",        
          error: function(){  
          $(".viewcat-error").html("");
          $("#viewcat").append('<tbody class="viewcat-error"><tr><th colspan="7">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
          $("#viewcat_processing").css("display","none");          
          }
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

Please help me to fix it..

Comment: Where is the code for `iCheck` activation?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    //iCheck for checkbox and radio inputs
    $('input[type="checkbox"].minimal, input[type="radio"].minimal').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue'
    });
});
</script>

Comment: Put `//iCheck for checkbox and radio inputs $('input[type="checkbox"].minimal, input[type="radio"].minimal').iCheck({ checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue', radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue' });` in `$.ajax.success` after appending data to table;

Comment: ajax success is not supportive for jQuery datatable..it doesn't provide any result

Comment: What about this `"ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {` provided here [ajax datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

Comment: if succes happens,no need of extra codes inside jQuery datatable..the plugin will automatically bind inside the called table..thats why if we are putting any code inside success it won't work..

Comment: But to init `iCheck` we need to use this to track html availability;

Comment: i think datatable having some special features..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh..Finally i found it..This may help others..One api function instead of ajax success is already there inside datatable plugin..That is "fnDrawCallback".

```
<script>
  $(function (){    
    $("#viewcat").DataTable({
      "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){               
               $("td:nth-child(2)", nRow).append(aData[7]);
               return nRow;
            },
      "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ){
              $('input[type="checkbox"].minimal, input[type="radio"].minimal').iCheck({
                  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
                  radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue'
                });},      
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "order": [ 2, "asc" ],
      "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 4, 5 ,6] } ],
      "ajax":{
          url :"maincategory/viewdata.php", // json datasource
          type: "post",        
          error: function(){  
          $(".viewcat-error").html("");
          $("#viewcat").append('<tbody class="viewcat-error"><tr><th colspan="7">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
          $("#viewcat_processing").css("display","none");          
          }
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```